# Font family top and bottom Padding different in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using 'Shruti' web fonts and they rendered differently in chrome and Firefox.

Added images are for textboxes and same things goes for other elements as well.I have already tried using padding in pixel/em but same thing again.

How to fix (vertical) font spacing problem in all browsers for consistency? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
line-height:10px;
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   line-height:10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   line-height:10px;
}
```

Try adding this to your css code, it will let you adjust the line height of the placeholder only for firefox to make it look like in chrome.

Change 10px for whatever you need.

About the other elements you should post an example with your code

Comment: But that will set only placeholder.What for textbox text?

Comment: @-moz-document url-prefix() { body { font-size: 100%; } } works to me to target firefox, if it is the one that gives you the problems

Comment: In Firefox text remains vertically centered but for chrome it goes vertically upwards.

Comment: still, it should be the same, if you use line height to align it correctly in chrome, then i'm guessing it will go downwards in firefox, use that rule i just posted to bring it back to it's correct place in firefox, does that make sense?